# Override .Mui-disabled (or other pseudo-classes/states) from the theme (MUI v4.1.X)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to override the global `.Mui-disabled` CSS rule from my theme overrides. I can do it for specific components like this (in Material-UI v4.1.x):

```
MuiTheme['overrides'] = {
  ...
  MuiMenuItem: {
    root: {
      ...root level overrides,
      '&.$Mui-disabled': {
        backgroundColor: 'inherit'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to avoid the need to add that to each different component and simply override the `.Mui-disabled` class rules once. Basically I don't want all disabled items to have the default grey colored background. Is there an easy way to do that from the theme?

Thanks for any insight!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was struggling to figure [how to override pseudo-classes](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/#pseudo-classes) myself. There are two approaches that I found;

globally when defining your custom theme;

```
export const CKWTheme = createMuiTheme({
    overrides: {
        MuiCssBaseline: {
            '@global': {
                //override the pseudo-classes
                '.Mui-disabled': { opacity: .5 }
                '.Mui-selected': { background: 'red' }
            }
        }
    },
});
```

which lot of times doesn't help, since they are applied more css-specific. In that case, you can override them when defining your style for a component;

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        root: {
            borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
            '&.Mui-disabled': {
                color: theme.palette.primary.main,
                opacity: 0.5,
            },
            '&.Mui-disabled:hover': { background:theme.palette.secondary.main },
        }
    }),
);
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay on accepting this, but I was holding out in hopes there was a better solution out there. Seems like maybe that's not the case. Thanks for throwing out a few different options.

Comment: @jbgarr no worries, I hope my solution helps. I have neither found another better approach since my answer :(

Answer (score 1):

For MUI v5

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
      components: {
      MuiCssBaseline: {
        styleOverrides: (theme) => ({
          '& .Mui-disabled': {
            cursor: 'not-allowed',
            '& *': {
              cursor: 'not-allowed !important',
            },
          },
          button: {
            '&:disabled': {
              cursor: 'not-allowed',
              pointerEvents: 'all !important',
            },
          },
        }),
      },
  },
});
```

[Official Docs Reference](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-css-baseline/)

Answer (score 1):

In MUI 5 for using styled for a specific button.

```
import { Button, styled } from "@mui/material";

const StyledButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&.Mui-disabled": {
    opacity: 0.6,
    pointerEvents: "auto",
    "&:hover": {
      cursor: "not-allowed",
      background: "skyblue",
    },
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying in MUI-4 , and it seems you can override in theme as well, for e.g -

```js
import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const theme = createTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiCheckbox: {
      colorPrimary: {
        '&.Mui-disabled': {
          color: '#your-custom-color'
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**MUI 5:**

You can override the default disabled values inside your theme's palette options as below:

```
import { ThemeOptions } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme: ThemeOptions = {
    palette: {
        action: {
            disabledOpacity: 0.48,
            disabledBackground: "",
            disabled: "",
        }
    },
}
```

**But be aware that all component's default disabled styles will be overridden and you must provide disabled styles individually for them through each component's `.Mui-disabled` class.**

Example for `Button` component:

```
const theme: ThemeOptions = {
    palette: {},
    components: {
        MuiButton: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: ({ theme }) => ({
                    "&.Mui-disabled": { opacity: 0.48 },
                }),
            },
        },
    },
};
```